# React template literals variable styling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, redux, styled-components

I have a variable named "one" which takes the string value "Robby" how do I style this variable? for example, set the color to red

```
const one = "Robby";

let initialState = {
    lessonsTitle: [
        {
            titleName: "JSON",
            iconName: faDotCircle,
            description: `
                ${one} advanced diverted domestic sex repeated bringing you old.
                Possible procured her trifling laughter
            `,
        },
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```
[`para 1.`, <br />, `para 2`]

description: [
  <span className="yourClass">{one}</span>,
  " advanced diverted domestic sex repeated bringing you old.
  Possible procured her trifling laughter"
]
```

Correct me if I'm wrong :)